# java equivalent for nsdate

Tags: java, android, nsdate

"NSDate timestamp" looks like "2012-12-11 18:30:41 - 400". The java timestamp is just a long integer (for example:"276712445500").

So, What is a Java equivalent for nsdate?

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you mean by "looks like". You can get *a string representation* of a `java.util.Date` using a `DateFormat` (e.g. `SimpleDateFormat`). You'd want to set the time zone yourself, though.

I believe that the internal structure of `NSDate` is basically equivalent to `java.util.Date`, based on [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> The sole primitive method of NSDate, timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate, provides the basis for all the other methods in the NSDate interface. This method returns a time value relative to an absolute reference date—the first instant of 1 January 2001, GMT.

In other words, the value doesn't "know" its offset from UTC etc... it's just a point in time. (The epoch and scale may well be different to `java.util.Date`, but that's an implementation difference more than a conceptual one.)

However, despite all of this I would strongly recommend that you use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) for all date/time manipulation in Java. It's a *much* nicer API than `java.util.Date`/`Calendar`.

Comment: +1 for Joda time. It's much nicer, can handle all situations, and is thread-safe.